# Expiration time of temporary URL returned by ee.data.getTileUrl(image.getMapId())

Tags: google-earth-engine

What is expiration time of temporary URL returned by `ee.data.getTileUrl(image.getMapId())`?

example:

> [https://earthengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/[project_name]/maps/[token]-[token]/tiles/6/11/24](https://earthengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/%5Bproject_name%5D/maps/%5Btoken%5D-%5Btoken%5D/tiles/6/11/24)

is there way to refresh it?

Answer (score 1):

> What is expiration time of temporary URL returned by `ee.data.getTileUrl(image.getMapId())`?

Earth Engine currently does not currently guarantee any specific time. They are intended for interactive use; i.e. the user visits a web page (causes `getMapId`) and then looks at tiles produced from that map for a while.

> is there way to refresh it?

It is not possible to extend the life of the URL; you must reissue the original `getMapId` request.

Comment: All that said, they're generally good for about 24 hours.  But there's no guarantee of that.